# What is wrong with how I'm passing MODE to rigctl for an ICOM IC-705?

Tags: icom

I'm using rigctl 4.5.5. on a pi zero and I can't figure out what is wrong with the way I'm passing the MODE value to my Icom IC-705.

Here it is not working.

```
❯ echo $RIGMODEL - $RIGPORT - $FREQ - $MODE
3085 - /dev/ttyACM0 - 144390000 - FM 12000
❯ rigctl --model=$RIGMODEL --rig-file=$RIGPORT set_freq $FREQ set_mode $MODE
Invalid arg for command 'set_mode'
```

Here it is working when I use the same value and no variable. I've tried wrapping it in quotes as well.

```
❯ rigctl --model=$RIGMODEL --rig-file=$RIGPORT set_freq $FREQ set_mode FM 12000
```

When you get_mode it is two lines and I've also tried using that or "\n" in the value as well.

```
❯ rigctl --model=$RIGMODEL --rig-file=$RIGPORT get_mode
FM
12000
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: seeing a space in between "FM" and "12000" makes me suspicious. Probably these two are treated as 2 separate arguments `FM` and `12000`, instead of the intended argument `FM 12000`. Can you try surrounding `$MODE` in straight double quotes, i.e., `"$MODE"`?